# Python Error when testing uWSGI in basic way

Tags: uwsgi

I'm just testing `uWSGI` by following the quick-start guide in official web site. But, I am facing a problem.
This is what I did. It's exactly same as the steps in quick guide.

```
$ uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file foobar.py

*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.19.1 (64bit) on [Sat Mar 12 09:28:41 2022] ***
compiled with version: Clang 11.0.0 on 18 January 2021 21:53:23
os: Darwin-21.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0: Wed Jan  5 21:37:58 PST 2022; root:xnu-8019.80.24~20/RELEASE_X86_64
nodename: mac-brian.local
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 16
current working directory: /Users/brian/Documents/project/uwsgi_test
detected binary path: /opt/anaconda3/envs/price_analysis/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 5568
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 256
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :9090 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 10349)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:59738 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.9.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 10 2021, 02:52:42)  [Clang 11.0.0 ]
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/price_analysis/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/price_analysis/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/price_analysis/lib/python3.9/_collections_abc.py", line 416, in <module>
    class _CallableGenericAlias(GenericAlias):
TypeError: type 'types.GenericAlias' is not an acceptable base type
```

And this is my `foobar.py`:

```
def application(env, start_response):
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
return [b"Hello World"]
```

After this I tried to connect to the `http://localhost:9090` in this way.

```
curl -v 127.0.0.1:9090
```

These are the responses.

```
curl -v 127.0.0.1:9090
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9090...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9090 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9090
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
>
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:59738" (0 retries): Connection refused
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:59738" (1 retries): Connection refused
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:59738" (2 retries): Connection refused
[uwsgi-http] unable to connect() to node "127.0.0.1:59738" (3 retries): Connection refused
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I expected `Hello World` but I get empty messages from the server.

How can I solve this?